# Inserting data from Excel into a table in outlook

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

**Update**
I have created an array to loop through some rows to grab data. I then want to insert this into the table I have already created in the outlook template.

**VBA Code**

```
Sub employeeArray()

    Dim managerEmployees() As Variant
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    Dim objWord
    Dim objDoc
    Dim objRange
    Dim objTable
    useractivity.Activate

    r = sheet1.ListObjects("Table1").ListRows.Count
    c = 8

    ReDim managerEmployees(1 To r, 1 To c)

    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = True
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
    Set objRange = objDoc.Range
    Set objTable = objDoc.Tables.Add(objRange, r, c)

    For r = LBound(managerEmployees, 1) To UBound(managerEmployees, 1)
        For c = LBound(managerEmployees, 2) To UBound(managerEmployees, 2)
        managerEmployees(r, c) = Range("A2").Offset(r, c).Value
        Next c
    Next r


    For r = LBound(managerEmployees, 1) To UBound(managerEmployees, 1)
        For c = LBound(managerEmployees, 2) To UBound(managerEmployees, 2)
        objTable.Cell(r, c).Range.Text = managerEmployees(r, c)
        Next c
    Next r

    Erase managerEmployees

    End Sub
```

**EXAMPLE - Outlook Template**

[image]

**EXAMPLE - Excel worksheet named sheet1 and table named Table1**

[image: Table of data]

Currently I am trying to open the table in word (only because I don't know how to do it in outlook, yet)

The Array is holding the data from the table and then creating a table in Word to paste the data in. This is now working although I now need to get this in Outlook rather than word

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You need to provide with us a simple example.

Comment: I have added an example for you

Comment: Where are you storing your information? Excel? Word? Text?

Comment: I'm storing all the information in Excel

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get the job done is to use the Word object model for modifying the message body.

The Outlook object model provides three different ways for working with item bodies:

1. Body - a plain text.
2. HTMLBody - an HTML markup.
3. The Word Editor. Outlook uses Word as an email editor, so you can use it to format the email message. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class which represents the message body.

You can read more about all these ways in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) in MSDN.

For example:

```
mail.GetInspector().WordEditor
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to include it by going to `Tools > References > Microsoft Excel 14.0` Library Object (14.0 is the version of your Excel. Mine is 2010).

Once done with that, you can proceed as follow:

```
Sub GetInfo()
'Define an Excel object
Dim ExcelApp As New Excel.Application
'Define objects
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim r As Object
Dim L As Long
'Visible = false meaning Excel will be running invisible
ExcelApp.Visible = False
Set WB = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("Path to Excel file")
Set WS = WB.Worksheets(1) '1 is the first sheet
L = WS.Cells(WS.Rows.Count, 1).End(-4162).Row 'finding the lastrow of data considering (1 means column A of your table. If A (1) is not in your table, change it to whatever letter)
Set r = WS.Range("A1:C" & L) 'Adjust it to the columns of your data
Dim Table As Variant 'Table is 1-based
Table = r.Value
'Quit Excel
WB.Close
ExcelApp.Quit

'Outlook goes go here

End Sub
```